# delay submit on form by 5 seconds and display jquery dialogue?

Tags: php, javascript, html, authentication

i need some help please. I am trying to delay the the submission of a form by 5 seconds so a jquery dialogue loading box appears before submitting the login form.

At the moment the code im using does delay the submit however it stops the form from submitting the data and wont log the user in.

I'm pretty sure its because im using e.preventDefault in my javascript however it doesnt work without it, can anyone please show me how i can delay the form from submitting and submit the data successfully so it does log the user in.

Thanks.

```
<div id="login">
      <?php
        if (!logged_in()) {
            ?>

      <form id="myform" form action="login.php" rel="shadowbox" method="post" class="loginform">

    Email
      <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" />

    Password
    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" />

    <input type="image" src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/loginarrow1.png" name="submit" class="loginbutton" value="Login" />

                </form>


               <?php
        }
        if (logged_in()) {
            ?>


                 Logged in as, <?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>. <a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a>, <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> |&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="dashboard.php"><div class="login_settings" id="login_settings"></div></a>
    <?php
        }





        ?></div>

        <script>
        $('#myform').submit(function (e) {
        var form = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function () {
            form.submit();
        }, 3000); // in milliseconds
    });
    </script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myform').submit(function() {Shadowbox.open({
            content:    '<iframe src="login.php" width="500" height="300" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; border:none;"></iframe>',
            player:     "html",
            height:     300,
            width:      500
        });

             });



        });



    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single submit handler. I tried this on my local system and it works.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
                var form = this;
                e.preventDefault();

                Shadowbox.open({
                    content:    '<iframe src="login.php" width="500" height="300" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; border:none;"></iframe>',
                    player:     "html",
                    height:     300,
                    width:      500
                });

                setTimeout(function () {
                    form.submit();
                }, 3000); // in milliseconds
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: what did you do to make it work for you, because its delaying submit and bringing up the dilaogue window but not login the user in, what browser are you using etc?

Comment: i am using Chrome. Why are you loading login.php in iframe in shadowbox? The form.submit will submit the form #myform to the page specified in the action attribute of #myform. What are you exactly planning at achieving ?

Comment: im just using it as an example php file at the moment, im going to use content: <iframe> to display a loading gif.

Comment: for whatever reason though its not login the user in, im not sure how you got it to work.

Comment: I do not have your login.php server side code neither the code in the function logged_in(). I have just tested the delay and shadowbox. In essence whether the form was submitted after 3 seconds and whether the shadow box appeared or not! care to share the login.php and logged_in() in your question above?